# What is the best way to store DateTime into cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, cookies

I am working on an ASP .NET project, and currently I am using this code to store and retrieve DateTime on cookies:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
if (Request.Cookies["myCookie"] != null)
{
    cookie = Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
}
else
{
    cookie["From"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToShortDateString();
    cookie["To"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
model.FromDate = DateTime.Parse(cookie["From"]);
model.ToDate = DateTime.Parse(cookie["To"]);
```

And in my View I am using Razor to recovery the model values like this:

```
<input type="text" id="from" value="@Model.FromDate.ToShortDateString()" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" id="to" value="@Model.ToDate.ToShortDateString()" readonly="readonly" />
```

It is working fine when I run it locally, but when I uploaded to production, when recovering the DateTime from cookie, the date is changed in one day. For example, I selected a date range from 3/25/2016 to 4/1/2016, then I have gone to another page, and when I came back to this page, the page showed a date range from 3/24/2016 to 3/31/2016, decreased in one day.

Do you know what I am doing wrong here, why this just happens in production (I suppose is something related to server date) and, finally, what is the best way to store and retrieve a DateTime on cookie?

Comment: Where is the production server located?

Comment: I am not sure but I believe it is located in UK. I am using Octopus to deploy.

Comment: I checked the IP and it is located in Malta.

Comment: You might want to consider doing everything in UTC (DateTime.UtcNow) and using the .Net functions around timezones if you know your users' timezones.

Comment: A long time back I wrote about managing date time across client in different time zone http://www.cshandler.com/2011/07/setting-your-website-datetime-according.html see if it helps...

Comment: I tried changing from DateTime.Now to DateTime.UtcNow but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Cookie has timezone, so server can retrieve the date back from the cookie with correct time zone - doesn't matter what time zone client is in. The issue you run into might be that browser displays the cached page or some other codes that we do not know about.

Comment: If the safety is important here, don't forget to encrypt `DateTimes` values before save in in the cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When storing date / time as `string` you should always consider **timezones.** I recommend you to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`:

```
var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var asString = now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var asDatetimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(asString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The string looks like this: `04/01/2016 22:01:09 +02:00`

(You need to know the client's timezone to correctly calculate its 'local' time. In your example, the server uses it's own time.)

The result of `DateTime.Parse(cookie["From"]);` is set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. Any further operation (like AddDays) depends the system's timezone.

I think you should specify the culture and tell the parser which `DateTimeKind` to expect:

```
model.FromDate = DateTime.Parse(cookie["From"], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
model.ToDate = DateTime.Parse(cookie["To"], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

*Note*: DateTime.ToShortDateString isn't a good choice, since it is defined by the current culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object.

Comment: The problem was related to timezones. I solved it in a different way, but this answer was really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can store the date in Ticks

```
cookie["From"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Ticks.ToString();
cookie["To"] = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

and recover like this:

```
model.FromDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(cookie["From"]));
model.ToDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(cookie["To"]));
```

Hope this helps you